# Как получить определенное значение из mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Используя mongodb я имею в базе данных такой объект:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61adcb3d65227489649bbd73"),
  email: 'example@gmail.com',
  history: [ '7.11.2021', 'Вход' ]
}
```

Мне требуется получить массив history, что я и пытаюсь реализовать следующим образом:

```
    dateAction = await users.findOne({email: email}, {_id: 0, history: 1});
```

Но вместо ожидаемого массива dateAction получает весь объект. Что я делаю неправильно? Самое странное, что когда я пробовал это же в локальной базе данных в mongo-shell, все работало как надо.

P.S.
Я попробовал это:

```
const db = client.db('first-project');
dateAction = await db.collection('users').findOne({email: email}, {_id: 0, history: 1});
```

Никакой разницы. Мне кажется, я творю какой-то бред.

Comment: Странно, у меня и так `db.getCollection('user').findOne({email: 'example@gmail.com'}, {_id: 0, history: 1});`   и так `db.getCollection('user').findOne({email: { $exists: true }}, {_id: 0, history: 1});` возвращает только массив

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/

Comment: @Rudi, у меня метод getCollection выдает ошибку: TypeError: db.getCollection is not a function